# How to enable cookies and JavaScript on an android phone?

Tags: android-versions, javascript, cookies

While trying to login my Hackerearth account it put up a disclaimer that my cookies are disabled.Plus many times,many web pages tell me the same thing,and yeah,also ask me to enable JavaScript on my phone.

I own an HTC desire 620g.Unsure if that was necessary though

Comment: I think you should mention the name of the  browser you're using. The whole phone has nothing to with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the [cookies](http://www.whatarecookies.com/) and [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) are the features of Browsers which help it render the HTML web page content.

Assuming you are using **Google Chrome** Browser on your Android phone, you can actually enable both cookies and JavaScript through **Settings** of Google Chrome Browser.

Just go to **Settings** of Google Chrome Browser (Open Google Chrome Browser and click on 3-vertical dotted lines to right most corner). Click on **Site Settings**.

You should see a List of option which should include Cookies and JavaScript too.
You can toggle these individually by clicking them.

[image]

I guess instruction for enabling these should be similar to other browsers too (Although I did not tried it myself)

**Caution:** It is totally YOUR personal decision if you wanted to Allow cookies or JavaScript  or Not. This post is only meant as a helping guide to locate these settings of your browser. 
**Do it at your own [risk](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/risk-associated-cookies/).**

Comment: Why is it a risk?Does it like,allow the sites I visit to cause me serious damage or something?

Comment: like anything on internet, you have to be careful with cookies. Here is a link for more info: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/risk-associated-cookies/

Comment: And also I do not use Google chrome.Whenever a site is clicked on Google two options appear: Chrome,Internet.I choose the second

Comment: so, that means you have 2 browser installed on your device. you may choose either of them